# PHP код внутри js скрипта

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день! Хочу заставить работать php внутри js-скрипта. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, что я делаю е так?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

setTimeout('location.replace("http://ya.ru/?subid=<?php $subid = 
$_GET['subid']; { echo $subid; } ?>")',5000); 

</script>
```

Comment: И что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: PHP - серверный язык. Он никогда не заработает у пользователя в браузере

Comment: Если subid у вас известен в момент формирования страницы, то php корректно подставит значение в ссылку и она прямо в таком виде и будет лежать внутри js скрипта, так что по идее все должно работать. Но php разумеется только сформирует этот JS скрипт до того как он окажется на странице и заработает.

Comment: Не работает код. Суть: хочу, чтобы из ссылки код забирал параметр subid, затем передавал этот subid в новую ссылку, которую я указала в редиректе при таймауте. 
Да, я знаю. Потому храню решение на серваке, где стоит апач.

Comment: Так тоже не работает? `setTimeout('location.replace("http://ya.ru/?subid=<?= $_GET['subid'] ?>")',5000); ` Если нет, то покажите строку, которая формируется в браузере

Comment: Не формируется, просто не редиректит.

Comment: @Kira что вам нужно сделать?

Comment: @Kira, откройте в браузере фиговину, в которой Вы смотрите код сформированной страницы (в chrome это F12 и вкладка Elements), найдите там именно вот этот кусок `setTimeout('location.replace...` и посмотрите **что** подставилось туда, где вы пишете. Если вдруг по какой-то причине там не подставилось вообще ничего, то... это значит, что у Вас ничего и нет в `$_GET['subid']`. Спойлер: магия существует, но не в php и не в javascript.

Comment: Заработало, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// Приняли и записали данные в переменную
$subid = $_GET['subid'];


echo '<input type="hidden" name="subid" value="' . $subid  . '">';
```

?>

setTimeout(function() {
            location.replace('http://ya.ru/?subid=' + $('input[name="subid"]').val());
        }, 5000);

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение очень помогла найти ошибку у меня.